# JavaScript/Angular Trigger Form Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Update:

If I am filling out the AngularJS Forms with simple code below.

```
 document.getElementByID("username").value = "ZSAdmin"
 document.getElementByID("password").value = "SuperSecure101"
```

how can I cause the AngularJS Form validation before calling:

```
document.querySelectorAll("form[name='loginForm'] button.icon-login")[0].click()


<form name="loginForm" ng-submit="login()" autocomplete="off" class="ng-dirty ng-valid ng-valid-required">
<button type="submit" class="icon-login" ng-disabled="!loginForm.$valid"></button>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username / Email" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" required="" ng-model="credentials.username" class="ng-dirty ng-valid ng-valid-required">
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" required="" ng-model="credentials.password" class="ng-dirty ng-valid ng-valid-required">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs for [ng-submit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit), it "prevents the default action (which for form means sending the request to the server and reloading the current page), but only if the form does not contain action, data-action, or x-action attributes."

So I don't think you can submit the form. You could click your submit button though:

`document.querySelectorAll("form[name='loginForm'] button.icon-login")[0].click()`

Update:

If you want to change the values programatically to trigger angular's digest cycle i.e. update the form validations, you have to access the angular scope:

```
var $scope = angular.element("#username").scope();
$scope.$apply(function() {
  $scope.credentials.username = "ZSAdmin";
  $scope.credentials.password = "SuperSecure101";
  #you can even trigger the login from here if you want instead of the button click in the answer above:
  $scope.login();
});
```

Comment: This triggers an error with angular. And does not work either. :/ also I can't change the HTML as it is to a website that I have not control over

Comment: What is the angular error? If it is because you cannot change the html, then I am assuming it cannot find the button by id as it has none. I have changed the answer to locate the button by the class within the form i.e. it should be able to locate the button without changing the html

Comment: This is veryyy close.

The Only issues is because of `class="ng-dirty ng-valid ng-valid-required`

Angular doesn't validate the fields because I set them like `document.getElementByID("username").value = "Zachary"`

Comment: Updated answer to change the data via accessing angular scope. If you are accessing the scope you can also trigger the form submit from there too i.e. call the `login()` function that is called in the `ng-submit`